# Resize Thumb to have good quality

Tags: javascript, thumbnails, blogger

I am building a new blogger template , so i want to change the size of thumb to have good quality 
see this to know that i mean

**First Link**
[http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-Z3ehpCSmr7Q/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAADqQ/N1vT4RZldjM/**s35-c**/photo.jpg](http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-Z3ehpCSmr7Q/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAADqQ/N1vT4RZldjM/s35-c/photo.jpg)

**Second Link**
[http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-Z3ehpCSmr7Q/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAADqQ/N1vT4RZldjM/**s200-c**/photo.jpg](http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-Z3ehpCSmr7Q/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAADqQ/N1vT4RZldjM/s200-c/photo.jpg)

**here is my JS code**

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('IMG');
for(i = 0 ; i < x.length ; i++){
    var y = document.getElementsByTagName('IMG')[i];
    var z = y.getAttribute('src');
    var m = z.search('s35-c');
    if(m == -1){
        // NO THING
    } else{
        var d = z.replace('s35-c','s60-c');
        document.getElementsByTagName('IMG')[i].getAttribute('src') = d;
    };
}
```

when I execute this code , I have this error.

```
Invalid left-hand side in assignment
```

for this line

```
document.getElementsByTagName('IMG')[i].getAttribute('src') = d;
```

I also want to know how to change this part `s35-c` before image loaded ,
thank :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I GOT IT FINALLY

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('IMG');
for(i = 0 ; i < x.length ; i++){
var y = document.getElementsByTagName('IMG')[i];
var z = y.getAttribute('src');
var m = z.search('s35-c');
if(m == -1){
// NO THING
}else{
document.getElementsByTagName('IMG')[i].removeAttribute('src');
var d =  z.replace("s35-c","s100-c");
document.getElementsByTagName('IMG')[i].setAttribute('src', d);
};
}
```

Comment: Well, you got it fixed. You forgot to mention he fix: you were assigning a value to the result of `getAttribute()` instead of using `setAttribute()`. Also, why are you skipping intentation and fetching ALL THE IMAGES at least `n^2` times? When you can get them once and loop over them?

Comment: can you explain !

Comment: What's your exact question?

Comment: i did't get what you said !

Comment: I said that you are missing an explanation of what you did to fix your code and a description of what was wrong. You simply threw unindented code into the answer and done.